# Magento 2 URL structure

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, url

I Need a module or solution that can change Magneto2.1.9 URL generator.Actually want my URL to be like

This `https://www.example.com/folder/product-name-SKU`

the folder is **my stores**.

Right now it generates just **by name(not name and SKU)** by default.

If anybody knows about **google Search Engine Optimization new URL structure**.

Comment: while product add,place the product name and sku in the product url.. thats it

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i want to set it automatically, not 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [mageplaza URL generator extension...](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-seo-extension/)
it has all your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the `vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Model/ProductUrlPathGenerator.php`

override the below function in your module

`function prepareProductUrlKey()`

Replace the line number `138`

from

```
return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() : $urlKey);
```

To

```
return $product->formatUrlKey($urlKey === '' || $urlKey === null ? $product->getName() . "-" . $product->getSku() : $urlKey);
```